# Netbeans Database Project Build and Dis

Tags: database, netbeans, build, compilation, derby

I have just made a inventory and stock management system for my friend's shop.

I used Netbeans and Derby Database which comes built-in in netbeans.

I have completed my project(first project). Now i want to distribute this project to my friend and other people.

I Clean and Build the project. Its gives me a dis folder. When  i launch inventory.jar file and i give him username and password to login. It prompts me a message that i am not connected to database.

When i open my netbeans and connect to database than lauch inventory.jar file it works fine.

I WANT TO KNOW HOW TO GIVE MY PROJECT TO OTHER PEOPLE. WHATS THE WAY TO BUILD DATABASE APPLICATION.

my other question are?

Do i have to make database in all computer in which i run the application.
Do i have to install netbeans than create database than run the project

i am noob i have no idea what to do next. plzzz help me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please fix typos/grammar and avoid all-caps; if the question is easy to read, you'll have better chances to get an answer !

Comment: Best way to get started with Derby: read the Derby tutorials, and work through them by hand, yourself. Here they are: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/getstart/

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case you need to export databse from phpmyadmin and need to import on other computer. This is happening because your applications is still looking for same specific database name that you had given in your apps.